# I didn't read any requirements and was refused visa under Appendix V

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

My dad was going for a surgery on his shoulder this month and he invited me over to assist him for awhile. I have a 3-year-old child, so I applied for the both of us and we were refused a visa.

I had already been given visas to the UK when I was in school, so I thought it was the same process. My husband is in Italy now, and he was the sponsor. When I sent the documents, I did not translate any of them. Also, I ticked unemployed instead of self employed.

My dad is out of surgery and alone in the apartment and not able to move much. I have my own business and I will never jeopardize my child's life for anything. Next summer, we will be on holidays in Italy.

Can I apply with all the necessary documents? How soon can I apply?

Comment: Is elder care within ones own family something the UK considers "employment" ?

Comment: The hospital where the treatment took place should have done a discharge assessment to look at care needs at home and what care is available, if the patient is eligible https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/social-care-and-support/hospital-discharge-care/ I can’t find a source regarding ‘employment’ for visiting carers, however if the proposed stay is proportionate and the applicant’s ties to home/finances etc are strong an ECO has discretion to consider the compassionate grounds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There’s no ‘waiting time’ before you can apply again, you are free to submit another application straightaway. You’ll need to pay very careful attention to the published requirements, and make sure that you a) address the reason(s) for the refusal; and b) provide a clear and succinct explanation for any factual errors in your previous application eg ‘I ticked ”unemployed” by mistake and did not notice the error before I submitted the application’ 
Edit: while the circumstances are somewhat different, reading this answer may help [I've applied for a UK Standard Visitor visa to attend to my sick husband, but my application was refused. How should I reapply?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/86645/ive-applied-for-a-uk-standard-visitor-visa-to-attend-to-my-sick-husband-but-my?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)